# Where is the database saved in HTML5?

Tags: database, html

I am new to HTML5. I have created a database in HTML5 using some tutorial. But I am not able to understand where the database is saved. Please help me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button1").click(function() {
    var db = openDatabase("databasename", "1.0", "databasedes", 200000);
    alert("database has been created ");
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
      tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo (id unique, text)');
      tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO foo (id, text) VALUES (1, "foobar1")');
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check our database via, fo example, Chrome debugger (tab Resources -> Web SQL), but browser has special model for saving this data

Answer (score 0):

#### There are two types of storage.

**LocalStorage and SessionStorage**

HTML5 Web Storage defines two types of key-value storage types: sessionStorage and localStorage. The primary behavioral difference is how long the values persist and how they are shared. The following table shows the differences between the two types of storage.

[image]

Check out [Developer's Guide - Client-side Storage (Web Storage)](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5Storage) for more information.